# Why was my answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answer

I posted [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/472081/can-i-force-a-greater-screen-brightness-from-windows-command-prompt/1004289#1004289), which was deleted. Why was it deleted?

[image]

Added image of deleted post for <10k users.

Comment: @SilQ - Because what you submitted is a comment.  Comments submitted as an answer will always be reported, flagged, and eventually deleted by a moderator.

Comment: On a side note.  Given the excellent answers for that question.  I am not sure what you value your answer would bring, as it is currently written, if had not been deleted.

Answer (score 13):

*While I am not Journeyman Geek...*

The answer as written is clearly not an attempt at answering the question stated in the question post at the top of the page.

Hence, your text was posted as an answer, but **does not actually attempt to answer the question.** The answer thus was almost certainly deleted because it does not meet our criteria for what constitutes an answer.

For further discussion about what we like to see in answers and why some answers are deleted, see [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers) and [How do I write a good answer?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) in our [help center](https://superuser.com/help).

Comment: I'm Journeyman Geek, and I think this is a reasonable answer ;p

Comment: Funny, all this time I thought you were @JourneymanGeek♦.

Comment: There's a space, and OH MY GOD THERE IS A DIAMOND ON MY TAIL.

Answer (score 7):

We expect answers to actually answer the question. If you want to leave a comment, use the comment links. If you don't have permission to leave a comment, then you don't have permission to leave a comment. If you want to ask your own question, then ask your own question.

Answer (score 5):

I'm the mod that deleted it. Quite a lot of the time I try to give the answer the benefit of the doubt, but sometimes there's little in the answer that makes it worth salvaging.

Lets consider one *very simple* criteria. *Does it attempt to solve the problem in the question?*

No.

For conversion to a comment *is it clear which question this comment is for?* And *does it add to the body of knowledge we are building?*

Nope on both counts.

As such, this "answer" wasn't worth keeping, nor could I find a way to salvage it.

The fact that this question was originally asked *on the main site* suggests to me that you might need to give the [tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and [help](https://superuser.com/help) pages a read, and attempt to better understand how SU works.

Comment: Note that the OP doesn't actually have the reputation to participate on meta.

Comment: My bad. That said, the recommendations to read the tour and help pages stand. I also didn't realise how the original question was worded, which makes me wonder if something was lost in translation.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The original question was [Can I force a greater screen brightness from Windows Command Prompt](https://superuser.com/q/472081). I guess he was wanting explanation of one of the answers.